# 3D Designing programs such as Google Sketchup, Blender, Wings 3D crash on my 64bit Win 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, 3d, 3d-modeling

Google Sketchup, Blender, Wings 3D,  Maya and all such programs, whenever started, crash. Google Sketchup produces a bug splat but doesn't say anything specific about the error, Wings 3D and blender just directly crash with windows crash dialog appearing and saying "Blender.exe has stopped working". What could be the possible causes of this and how could it be corrected?

My Configuration:
Windows 7 64-bit
RAM 4GB
Processor: Core i3 2.27GHz
Intel HD Graphics.

Comment: You need a graphics chipset that supports OpenGL for most of those. Please add the specific Intel graphics chipset.

Comment: I can only see this much in the 'display' tab of dxdiag.
"Intel HD Graphics (Core i3)"